# Running wires through a decorative drop ceiling

Tags: electrical

[image: Decorative drop ceiling]

I have a room where my plaster and lath ceiling is cracking. I was thinking about putting this up and then running my new wires through them because I also have to rewire the house. Instead of running my wires through the attic. I could hang these on one by threes that are hung on the ceiling and then I'll have a channel for my wire to run in.

Comment: That's a lovely statement. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ & Answer forum. What's your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question.

Comment: Billy Bob seems to be one of Judson's (lion tiger, bob the builder, etc...all removed by moderators.) sock puppets, or my nephew is a spidertail. Which means an actual licensed electrician is needed for the "house" that is actually part of a multiple dwelling unit.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Thinking the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have to run electrical cables 1.25in away from the back of any finishing panel, incl. drywall boards or decorative panels. That's why we drill wire holes in the center of a 2x4 stud.

In your case you'd have to ensure that the wires are 1.25in away from the back of the ceiling panel. This means you could use 2x2 lumber for strapping the panels, and run wires flat against the old ceiling. If you use 1x3 it would have to be on edge not flat.

Alternatively you can use armoured cable or apply a sleeve to your cable, or run them through metallic conduit. Or you can run the cables flat against the ceiling and cover them with metallic plates (1/16in thick), before applying the ceiling panel.